# How to find the connected component

Tags: graph, arangodb

I have a graph, I want to put the vertices connected in the graph in a group，So I can divide a graph into many small graph, Then add a label to each of these thumbnails.

In that case I can traverse my thumbnail by adding conditions to improve efficiency and the vertices in the small graph are connected directly or indirectly. These small graph are called connected components of the large graph, I want to know if there is an algorithm that can fulfill my needs.

Comment: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/Manual/Graphs/Pregel/

Comment: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/Manual/Graphs/Pregel/                                     
I used Connected Components, arangodb's own algorithm.But the result is not what I want，
He can not divide the connected vertices well, it is affected by the direction，I want to get the weak connected component，https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/4062                                         
GitHub above my question you can see，thank you  @Arun Vinoth